# Class method won't display results

Tags: c#, class, console

For some reason class method getTime() won't output on the console screen the time. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Does `Console.WriteLine("Heloo");` output to the console?

Comment: @Stainless: Did you try `Console.WriteLine(h)`?

Comment: @climbage Yes. Heloo outputs, but if I place it after the object creation and the get method it doesn't.
@Marnix Nope.
@jsmith Nope.

Comment: have you tried to set a breakpoint in the getTime() method? Does it get hit?

Comment: you are not setting variables value for example in setM(int minutes) method u r not setting variable `m` value outside `WHILE`

Comment: This is random but why do you declare the private methods getS()/getH()/getM(). They just return your private variables, and you never use them. Are they meant to be public?

Comment: @jsmith When there will be operator overloaded functions I would use them. For example bool Equal(obj1,obj2) {return (obj1.getX() == obj2.getX()};

Comment: @Stainless, where has your code gone? Do you have your answer?

Answer (score 4):

Your set methods have infinite loops!

```
private void setM(int minutes)
{
    while (minutes > 59)
    {
        h++;
        m = minutes - 60;
    }
}
```

When will this method stop?

Comment: You're right. Fixed. But, isnt the right side evaluated first, aka minutes get subtracted then assigned to m. So eventually minutes would be less than 59. What did I miss?

Comment: @Stainless: No, because you are checking on `minutes`, but `minutes` never changes. You save `(minutes - 60)` into `m`. But `minutes` will still be of the same value. You have to say: `minutes = minutes - 60`, as StackOverflowException suggests. When you are done with your while-loop, you can set `m = minutes`, so that the remaining minutes are set into `m`.

Answer (score 2):

The while loops in couple functions never return.
Try

```
        private void setM(int minutes)
        {
            while (minutes > 59)
            {
                h++;
                minutes-=60;
            }
            m = minutes;
        }
```

and

```
       private void setS(int seconds)
        {
            while (seconds > 59)
            {
                m++;
                seconds-=60;
            }
            s = seconds;
        }
```

Comment: Huh, that's what my first iteration of those methods looked like, but I without even testing tried to "simplify" them.  Thanks